# What does "| “ (before integers) mean in mysql when trying to store INT in column customerid?

Tags: mysql

[image: table customer]

[image: table orders]

I am loading 2 local flat files with the same customerID data in mysql; the results are shown in the above pictures. I am curious that why the customerId in table customer has "|"+ numbers while table order doesn't.

How should I fix it, and why it shows in this way?

Comment: The `|` is part of the formatting that MariaDB uses.  I don't know why the `|` aren't aligned to the left, like they should be.  To see that the `|` isn't part of the data, instead of `;` end the query with `\G`.  `SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT 10 \G`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the csv-file uses `\r\n` as a line break, so when you specify `lines terminated by '\n'`, the data in the last column will include the `\r` (as that column only ends at the `\n`). Try to use `load data infile ... lines terminated by '\r\n'` or remove that character some other way afterwards.

So this has nothing to do with the integer column, but with the attempt to output the firstname column in a nice way. When MySQL tries to e.g. print out `DANIEL` formatted as a table, it will add some spaces and a `|`. Since the name includes an `\r`, this will actually turn into something like `... | DANIEL\r   |`, and your console will take this `\r` as a sign to jump to the beginning of the line, overwriting your first column with some spaces and the final `|`. You'll notice that there are more spaces when the firstname is shorter.

Comment: This would explain why the table is being drawn all weird.